# Teiid Dialect for Hibernate 6

Tags: hibernate, teiid, dialect

I'm using Teiid since 2010 in many projects with Hibernate 5.x and now I'm planning to migrate to Hibernate 6.

Do anyone know if current teiid dialect works with Hibernate 6 or if someone is developing the new dialect?

Thank you and I appreciate for the help.

Antonio

Answer (score 0):

currently, none are available. Did you try using hibernate 5 version? We are currently not actively working on this project because lack of wide community interest.

Comment: Hi Reddy, thanks for the reply. I tried using the current Teiid dialect (for H5) but it conflicts with hibernate 6. Looking further inside the Hibernate 6 dialect, this is very different from the previous version. For this, if you agree, I'm trying to write a new dialect. Can I send it to you once I'm done to check and share? Another question: We are currently using Teiid version 16.0.0. Do you think we could migrate to version 17 which is in master? thanks, Antonio